# How can I append a new path to python?

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

Since I updated to python 3.9.1 I have problems to load some functions I created and stored in a different path. Previously, I was working with python 3.6.8 and the function import worked. The code I use for importing is the following:

```
sys.path.append("[absolute path to folder]") # add to python path
from [python file name without .py] import [function name in file]
```

If I execute the previous lines one by one, I get following error:

`[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

The full message is:

```
[2021-01-12 08:27:57,081] DEBUG    matplotlib   (private) matplotlib data path: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data
[2021-01-12 08:27:57,081] DEBUG    matplotlib   matplotlib data path: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data
[2021-01-12 08:27:57,095] DEBUG    matplotlib   CONFIGDIR=C:\Users\user\.matplotlib
[2021-01-12 08:27:57,098] DEBUG    matplotlib   matplotlib version 3.3.3
[2021-01-12 08:27:57,099] DEBUG    matplotlib   interactive is False
[2021-01-12 08:27:57,100] DEBUG    matplotlib   platform is win32
[2021-01-12 08:27:57,101] DEBUG    matplotlib   loaded modules: ["here all the loaded modules"]
[2021-01-12 08:27:57,171] DEBUG    matplotlib   CACHEDIR=C:\Users\user\.matplotlib
[2021-01-12 08:27:57,181] DEBUG    matplotlib.font_manager Using fontManager instance from C:\Users\user\.matplotlib\fontlist-v330.json
[2021-01-12 08:27:57,531] DEBUG    matplotlib.pyplot Loaded backend tkagg version unknown.
[2021-01-12 08:27:57,531] DEBUG    matplotlib.pyplot Loaded backend TkAgg version unknown.
[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Digging a bin on the function I've discovered that the error is an import error from the seaborn module, because if I import it I get:

```
import seaborn as sns 
[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Any clues of what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible the libraries you're attempting to use are not yet compatible with your new python version, check the documentations for seaborn and matplotlib to find out what the latest python version they are made for is. Generally it's best to stay a couple of minor versions behind the latest python release to give third party libraries some leeway to catch up

Comment: It's just what you are saying. I updated the seaborn library and the problem is gone. Now the problem is with another library, but thanks for the clue and the advice!